# Understanding Javascript Query error?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
 function querySchools() {

          var query = quakesLayer.createQuery();

          query.where = "District = '" + dom.byId("district").value + "'"; 


          return quakesLayer.queryFeatures(query);


      }

      function displayResults(results) {

          resultsLayer.removeAll();

          var features = results.features.map(function (graphic) {
              graphic.symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
                  style: "diamond",
                  size: 6.5,
                  color: "darkorange"
              });
              return graphic;
          });
          var numSchools = features.length;

          dom.byId("results").innerHTML = numSchools + " schools found";

          var text;

          for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
              text += features[i].attributes.RegistrationName + "<br>";
          }

          dom.byId("results").innerHTML = dom.byId("results").innerHTML + text;

          console.log(features);

          resultsLayer.add(features);

      }
```

queryschools() function works correctly, but displayresults() not doesn't work correctly. features didn't appears on the map.

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling displayresults before the [queryFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryfeatures) method has returned its results. That method returns a Deferred, meaning you have to wait for the results. You have to run that something like

```
quakesLayer.queryFeatures(query, displayresults);
```

Or

```
quakesLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
  resultsLayer.removeAll();

  var features = results.features.map(function (graphic) {
      graphic.symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
          style: "diamond",
          size: 6.5,
          color: "darkorange"
      });
      return graphic;
  });
  var numSchools = features.length;

  dom.byId("results").innerHTML = numSchools + " schools found";

  var text;

  for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      text += features[i].attributes.RegistrationName + "<br>";
  }

  dom.byId("results").innerHTML = dom.byId("results").innerHTML + text;

  console.log(features);

  resultsLayer.add(features);
});
```